# EXC_BAD_ACCESS and stringByAppendingString

Tags: ios, sqlite, nsstring, exc-bad-access

Getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS when setting a label with the value returned by the following function defined in a class called DataHelper (all database handling done here):

```
+(NSString *)getCurrentBalanceAndType:(NSString *)account
{
    sqlite3_stmt *statement=NULL;
    float bal=0;
    NSString *type=NULL, *balance_type=NULL;
    //String decimalFormat="%.2f";
    statement = [DataHelper getDetailsFromAccountBal:account:[DataHelper currentMonth]];
    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        bal = sqlite3_column_double(statement,2);
        type = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
    } 
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);

    NSString *stringBal=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", bal];
    type=[[type uppercaseString] stringByAppendingString:@"r"];
    balance_type=[[stringBal stringByAppendingString:@" "]stringByAppendingString:type];
    [type release];
    return balance_type;
}
```

This is how I am setting the label in viewDidLoad:

```
 lbCreditCurrBal.text=[DataHelper getCurrentBalanceAndType:@"Some Text"];
```

Please help.

Comment: if you comment out the [type release] line, does that make any difference?

Comment: commenting this line leads to memory leak. i don't want to use ARC.

Answer (score 1):

You are overreleasing `type`. Remove `[type release];`. And use ARC to avoid this kind of errors.

Answer (score 1):

When you call a method that begins with anything except init or copy, you’re returned an object that will be autoreleased at some point in the future.
reference- [ray's memory management blog](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2657/memory-management-in-objective-c-tutorial)

keeping above in mind I think you should not release the type object as said by Nikolai.